# How to prevent usage of signatures that were given by fake websites after signing eth message?

Tags: authentication, security, ethereum, ethers.js

There're plenty of sites, where you have to sign their 'sign in' message in order to get JWT from them. For example, https://www.cryptokitties.co uses such login system. It verifies the signature on the back-end and sends JWT back if address matches. It works good, but such approach disturbs me in the matter of security.

Assume, that someone has created absolutely identical to cryptokitties fake website. User hasn't noticed that domain is different, signs the same message ("*To avoid digital cat burglars, sign below to authenticate with CryptoKitties*") and at this point he already provided scammer with his signature and address, as message was the same, therefore it will work on original website. So basically you can loose your account by signing the same message on the completely different site. The saddest part, is that you cannot reset the private key, which means that your account has gone for good.

I'm not an expert, but it seems to me like a huge hole in security.
The solution I'm thinking about, is to encrypt the signature on the client before sending it on the back-end. With such approach, back-end will only send you a JWT if you've signed a message on our front-end. So, firstly back-end decrypts the signature and then verifies the message and address. It will skip signatures which were created on other sites as the decryption will fail.

So far we eliminated fake websites problem. But there is another one: attacker can intercept an already encrypted signature and use it on our site. And once again there is no way to reset the signature, it'll remain the same. So what I came up with is, signature must be disposable, it can be used only once. Before signing a message client requests from the back-end special random number linked with according wallet. Based on this number we build signature message like this: "*To avoid digital cat burglars, sign below to authenticate with CryptoKitties #564324*". Firstly, back-end decrypts the signature, verifies the address and then checks whether specified random number exists in database. Once login is succeeded, the random number is deleted from the database. Now, even if user looses his signature, it can't be used by attacker, because it's already expired.

What do you think? Does described approach make sense?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea with "signature must be disposable". The concept is called a **nonce** (a value used to protect private communications by preventing replay attacks).

Your following logic is correct as well, except that you don't need to delete the nonce from the database, but rather *rotate* it. *I.e.* update the value to a new pseudo-random (or at least hard to guess) value.

Comment: Got you, thanks!
Do you have any ideas, how can we deny on the back-end all signatures except the ones, generated on our front-end? Should we even care about it as developers?
I mean if our service asks to sign 'Sign in' message, then it's 100% that same signature can be generated on some other service. It's a very common message. So far, I think that we need to include our service name in the message. Still, it the matter of user's attention.

Comment: You're forgetting about the nonce. As you mentioned in your original post, the message will include the nonce (#564324). The user signs the message and the sends it to the backend, where the _same nonce_ is available for decryption. The backend will know about the message (same as frontend) and the nonce (fetched from db), and will be able to recover the signers address using something like Web3's recover function`web3.eth.accounts.recover(message, signature)`. If the recovered address is the same as the given wallet address, the user is authenticated and they are who they say they are.